# How to import xyz data in QGIS 3.0 Processing Modeler for creating points and raster?

Tags: raster, qgis-3, qgis-modeler, xyz, xyz-tiles

I want use dsm data in QGIS 3.0 Processing Modeler. This data are in xyz-format.
I want to convert xyz data into points to create a raster. Later I want also apply this modle for the a folder with several xyz data in a folder.
I have tried tool “create points form table”.  Doesn't worked
Outside the from Processing Modeler is possible to import xyz data  with  “delimited Text”

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what your question is? Is it how to load xyz data into QGIS or how to use this data in modeler? Or sth else?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Sorry for confusion. I want load xyz data in modeler to create points and later in progress a raster.